# Adding form fields to a ASPX C# application

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hey Sorry might seem like a silly question i normally develop in PHP and but i have to make changes to a web application that was built by a past developer and i dont really have any experience with .net

It should be easy fixed problem i have a web application at for managing employees in the fields when we add and edit employees i would just like to add an input for mobile phone numbers

below is what i have tried so far

i have added a field in the database call UserPhone

when i make the following changes it breaks the code and i am unsure now where i am going wrong its only one extra input field.

sorry this is might be a bit of code overload.

I added input field with ID="txtMobile" to aspx file

```
 <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="tbl_form">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4">
                <asp:Label ID="lblErrorMessage" runat="server" Text="" Visible="false" ForeColor="Red"
                    Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                *
            </td>
            <td>
                Employee Number
            </td>
            <td>
                :
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtEmployeeNumber" MaxLength="25" class="textfield"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="vEmployeeNumber" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtEmployeeNumber"
                    ErrorMessage="Employee Number Field is required" ValidationGroup="User"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                *
            </td>
            <td>
                First Name
            </td>
            <td>
                :
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtFirstName" MaxLength="25" class="textfield"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="vFirstName" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtFirstName"
                    ErrorMessage="First Name Field is required" ValidationGroup="User"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                *
            </td>
            <td>
                Last Name
            </td>
            <td>
                :
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtLastName" MaxLength="25" class="textfield"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="vLastName" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtLastName"
                    ErrorMessage="Last Name Field is required" ValidationGroup="User"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </td>
        </tr>
         <tr style="height: 29px; vertical-align: top;">
            <td>
                &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td>
               Mobile
            </td>
            <td>
                :
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtMobile" class="textfield" MaxLength="100"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="height: 29px; vertical-align: top;">
            <td>
                &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td>
                E Mail
            </td>
            <td>
                :
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtEMail" class="textfield" MaxLength="100"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="emailformat" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtEMail"
                    ValidationGroup="User" ErrorMessage="Please enter Email in proper format" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

C# Code Behind file
the i added one line of code to each function witch is commented out at the moment

```
protected void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        base.Response.Redirect("DisplayEmployee.aspx", false);
    }
    catch (SqlException sqlException)
    {
        BL_ErrorHandling.SQLExceptionHandling(sqlException, "ManageEmployee", "btnCancel_Click", "SQL Error in ManageEmployee");
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        BL_ErrorHandling.GeneralExceptionHandling(exception, "ManageEmployee", "btnCancel_Click", "General Error in ManageEmployee");
    }
}

protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        DataRow drNew = null;
        BL_UserMaster objUser = new BL_UserMaster(this.sConnStr);
        if (this.dsManageUser.Tables["User"].Rows.Count != 0)
        {
            this.gUserID = new Guid(this.dsManageUser.Tables["User"].Rows[0]["UserID"].ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            this.gUserID = Guid.NewGuid();
        }
        string ErrorMessage = "";
        ErrorMessage = objUser.CheckUserMasterForUniqueLoginNameAndEmpNo(this.gUserID, this.txtEmployeeNumber.Text, this.txtUserName.Text);
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ErrorMessage))
        {
            if (this.dsManageUser.Tables["User"].Rows.Count != 0)
            {
                drNew = this.dsManageUser.Tables["User"].Rows[0];
                drNew["UserIsActive"] = this.chkIsActive.Checked;
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.txtPassword.Text))
                {
                    drNew["UserPassword"] = this.txtPassword.Text;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                drNew = this.dsManageUser.Tables["User"].NewRow();
                drNew["UserID"] = this.gUserID;
                drNew["UserPassword"] = this.txtPassword.Text;
            }
            drNew["EmployeeNumber"] = this.txtEmployeeNumber.Text;
            drNew["UserFirstName"] = this.txtFirstName.Text;
            drNew["UserLastName"] = this.txtLastName.Text;
            drNew["UserEmailID"] = this.txtEMail.Text;
           // drNew["UserPhone"] = this.txtMobile.Text;
            drNew["UserOrganisationID"] = new Guid(this.ddlOrganisation.SelectedValue);
            drNew["UserVenueId"] = this.ddlVenue.SelectedValue;
            drNew["UserName"] = this.txtUserName.Text;
            drNew["UserRoleID"] = this.ddlRole.SelectedValue;
            if (this.dsManageUser.Tables["User"].Rows.Count == 0)
            {
                this.dsManageUser.Tables["User"].Rows.Add(drNew);
            }
            objUser.SaveUser(this.dsManageUser);
            this.btnCancel_Click(this.btnCancel, new EventArgs());
        }
        else
        {
            this.lblErrorMessage.Visible = true;
            this.lblErrorMessage.Text = ErrorMessage;
        }
    }
    catch (SqlException sqlException)
    {
        BL_ErrorHandling.SQLExceptionHandling(sqlException, "ManageEmployee", "btnSave_Click", "SQL Error in ManageEmployee");
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        BL_ErrorHandling.GeneralExceptionHandling(exception, "ManageEmployee", "btnSave_Click", "General Error in ManageEmployee");
    }
}

protected void DisplayData()
{
    try
    {
        BL_UserMaster objUser = new BL_UserMaster(this.sConnStr);
        this.dsManageUser = objUser.GetUser(this.gUserID);
        this.trActive.Visible = false;
        this.txtUserName.ReadOnly = false;
        if (this.dsManageUser.Tables["User"].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            this.txtEmployeeNumber.Text = this.dsManageUser.Tables["User"].Rows[0]["EmployeeNumber"].ToString();
            this.txtFirstName.Text = this.dsManageUser.Tables["User"].Rows[0]["UserFirstName"].ToString();
            this.txtLastName.Text = this.dsManageUser.Tables["User"].Rows[0]["UserLastName"].ToString();
            this.ddlOrganisation.SelectedValue = this.dsManageUser.Tables["User"].Rows[0]["UserOrganisationID"].ToString();
            this.ddlVenue.SelectedValue = this.dsManageUser.Tables["User"].Rows[0]["UserVenueId"].ToString();
            this.txtUserName.Text = this.dsManageUser.Tables["User"].Rows[0]["UserName"].ToString();
            this.txtPassword.Text = this.dsManageUser.Tables["User"].Rows[0]["UserPassword"].ToString();
            this.ddlRole.SelectedValue = this.dsManageUser.Tables["User"].Rows[0]["UserRoleID"].ToString();
            this.txtEMail.Text = this.dsManageUser.Tables["User"].Rows[0]["UserEmailID"].ToString();
            //this.txtMobile.Text = this.dsManageUser.Tables["User"].Rows[0]["UserPhone"].ToString();
            this.trActive.Visible = true;
            this.chkIsActive.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(this.dsManageUser.Tables["User"].Rows[0]["UserIsActive"]);
        }
        this.Session["dsManageUser"] = this.dsManageUser;
    }
    catch (SqlException sqlException)
    {
        BL_ErrorHandling.SQLExceptionHandling(sqlException, "ManageEmployee", "DisplayData", "SQL Error in ManageEmployee");
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        BL_ErrorHandling.GeneralExceptionHandling(exception, "ManageEmployee", "DisplayData", "General Error in ManageEmployee");
    }
}
```

User Master Class

```
using Microsoft.ApplicationBlocks.Data;
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace BLPubGroupTimeSheet
{
    public class BL_UserMaster
    {
        private string sConnString = "";

        public BL_UserMaster(string sConnectionString)
        {
            this.sConnString = sConnectionString;
        }

        public string ChangePassword(Guid UserID, string OLDPassword, string NewPassword)
        {
            SqlConnection objConn = new SqlConnection(this.sConnString);
            objConn.Open();
            string sMessage = "";
            try
            {
                try
                {
                    SqlParameter[] objParam = new SqlParameter[] { new SqlParameter("@UserID", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier), null, null, null };
                    objParam[0].Value = UserID;
                    objParam[1] = new SqlParameter("@UserOLDPassword", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20);
                    objParam[1].Value = OLDPassword;
                    objParam[2] = new SqlParameter("@UserNewPassword", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20);
                    objParam[2].Value = NewPassword;
                    objParam[3] = new SqlParameter("@Message", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
                    objParam[3].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                    SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(objConn, CommandType.StoredProcedure, "UpdateUserMasterForChangePassword", objParam);
                    sMessage = (objParam[3].Value != null ? objParam[3].Value.ToString() : "Error in updating password");
                }
                catch (SqlException sqlException)
                {
                    SqlException exsql = sqlException;
                    sMessage = "Error in updating password";
                    BL_ErrorHandling.SQLExceptionHandling(exsql, "BL_UserMaster", "ChangePassword", "SQL Error in BL_UserMaster");
                }
                catch (Exception exception)
                {
                    Exception ex = exception;
                    sMessage = "Error in updating password";
                    BL_ErrorHandling.GeneralExceptionHandling(ex, "BL_UserMaster", "ChangePassword", "General Error in BL_UserMaster");
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                objConn.Close();
            }
            return sMessage;
        }

        public DataSet CheckUserLogin(string UserName, string Password)
        {
            DataSet dsReturn = new DataSet();
            try
            {
                SqlParameter[] objParam = new SqlParameter[] { new SqlParameter("@UserName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50), null };
                objParam[0].Value = UserName;
                objParam[1] = new SqlParameter("@UserPassword", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20);
                objParam[1].Value = Password;
                dsReturn = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(this.sConnString, CommandType.StoredProcedure, "CheckUserLogin", objParam);
            }
            catch (SqlException sqlException)
            {
                BL_ErrorHandling.SQLExceptionHandling(sqlException, "BL_UserMaster", "CheckUserLogin", "SQL Error in BL_UserMaster");
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                BL_ErrorHandling.GeneralExceptionHandling(exception, "BL_UserMaster", "CheckUserLogin", "General Error in BL_UserMaster");
            }
            return dsReturn;
        }

        public string CheckUserMasterForUniqueLoginNameAndEmpNo(Guid UserID, string EmployeeNumber, string UserName)
        {
            string sErrorMessage = "";
            try
            {
                SqlParameter[] objParam = new SqlParameter[] { new SqlParameter("@UserID", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier), null, null, null };
                objParam[0].Value = UserID;
                objParam[1] = new SqlParameter("@EmployeeNumber", SqlDbType.VarChar, 25);
                objParam[1].Value = EmployeeNumber;
                objParam[2] = new SqlParameter("@UserName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
                objParam[2].Value = UserName;
                objParam[3] = new SqlParameter("@ErrorMessage", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
                objParam[3].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(this.sConnString, CommandType.StoredProcedure, "CheckUserMasterForUniqueLoginNameAndEmpNo", objParam);
                sErrorMessage = (objParam[3].Value != null ? objParam[3].Value.ToString() : "");
            }
            catch (SqlException sqlException)
            {
                SqlException exsql = sqlException;
                sErrorMessage = exsql.Message;
                BL_ErrorHandling.SQLExceptionHandling(exsql, "BL_UserMaster", "CheckUserMasterForUniqueLoginNameAndEmpNo", "SQL Error in BL_UserMaster");
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Exception ex = exception;
                sErrorMessage = ex.Message;
                BL_ErrorHandling.GeneralExceptionHandling(ex, "BL_UserMaster", "CheckUserMasterForUniqueLoginNameAndEmpNo", "General Error in BL_UserMaster");
            }
            return sErrorMessage;
        }

        public DataSet GetRole()
        {
            DataSet dsReturn = new DataSet();
            try
            {
                dsReturn = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(this.sConnString, CommandType.StoredProcedure, "GetRoleMaster");
                dsReturn.Tables[0].TableName = "Role";
            }
            catch (SqlException sqlException)
            {
                BL_ErrorHandling.SQLExceptionHandling(sqlException, "BL_UserMaster", "GetRole", "SQL Error in BL_UserMaster");
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                BL_ErrorHandling.GeneralExceptionHandling(exception, "BL_UserMaster", "GetRole", "General Error in BL_UserMaster");
            }
            return dsReturn;
        }

        public DataSet GetUser(Guid UserID)
        {
            DataSet dsReturn = new DataSet();
            try
            {
                SqlParameter[] objParam = new SqlParameter[] { new SqlParameter("@UserID", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier) };
                objParam[0].Value = UserID;
                dsReturn = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(this.sConnString, CommandType.StoredProcedure, "GetUserMaster", objParam);
                dsReturn.Tables[0].TableName = "User";
            }
            catch (SqlException sqlException)
            {
                BL_ErrorHandling.SQLExceptionHandling(sqlException, "BL_UserMaster", "GetUser", "SQL Error in BL_UserMaster");
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                BL_ErrorHandling.GeneralExceptionHandling(exception, "BL_UserMaster", "GetUser", "General Error in BL_UserMaster");
            }
            return dsReturn;
        }

        public DataSet GetUserForDisplay()
        {
            DataSet dsReturn = new DataSet();
            try
            {
                dsReturn = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(this.sConnString, CommandType.StoredProcedure, "GetAllUserMaster");
                dsReturn.Tables[0].TableName = "AllUser";
            }
            catch (SqlException sqlException)
            {
                BL_ErrorHandling.SQLExceptionHandling(sqlException, "BL_UserMaster", "GetUserForDisplay", "SQL Error in BL_UserMaster");
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                BL_ErrorHandling.GeneralExceptionHandling(exception, "BL_UserMaster", "GetUserForDisplay", "General Error in BL_UserMaster");
            }
            return dsReturn;
        }

        public bool ResetPassword(Guid UserID, string NewPassword)
        {
            SqlConnection objConn = new SqlConnection(this.sConnString);
            objConn.Open();
            bool bReturn = false;
            try
            {
                try
                {
                    SqlParameter[] objParam = new SqlParameter[] { new SqlParameter("@UserID", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier), null };
                    objParam[0].Value = UserID;
                    objParam[1] = new SqlParameter("@UserNewPassword", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20);
                    objParam[1].Value = NewPassword;
                    SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(objConn, CommandType.StoredProcedure, "UpdateUserMasterForResetPassword", objParam);
                    bReturn = true;
                }
                catch (SqlException sqlException)
                {
                    SqlException exsql = sqlException;
                    bReturn = false;
                    BL_ErrorHandling.SQLExceptionHandling(exsql, "BL_UserMaster", "ResetPassword", "SQL Error in BL_UserMaster");
                }
                catch (Exception exception)
                {
                    Exception ex = exception;
                    bReturn = false;
                    BL_ErrorHandling.GeneralExceptionHandling(ex, "BL_UserMaster", "ResetPassword", "General Error in BL_UserMaster");
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                objConn.Close();
            }
            return bReturn;
        }

        public void SaveUser(DataSet dsUser)
        {
            SqlConnection objConn = new SqlConnection(this.sConnString);
            objConn.Open();
            try
            {
                try
                {
                    string[] strArrays = new string[] { "UserID", "EmployeeNumber", "UserFirstName", "UserLastName", "UserOrganisationID", "UserVenueId", "UserName", "UserPassword", "UserRoleID", "UserPhone", "UserEmailID" };
                    SqlCommand objInsert = SqlHelper.CreateCommand(objConn, "InsertUserMaster", strArrays);
                    string[] strArrays1 = new string[] { "UserID", "EmployeeNumber", "UserFirstName", "UserLastName", "UserOrganisationID", "UserVenueId", "UserPassword", "UserRoleID", "UserPhone", "UserEmailID", "UserIsActive", "UserName" };
                    SqlCommand objUpdate = SqlHelper.CreateCommand(objConn, "UpdateUserMaster", strArrays1);
                    SqlHelper.UpdateDataset(objInsert, new SqlCommand(), objUpdate, dsUser, "User");
                }
                catch (SqlException sqlException)
                {
                    BL_ErrorHandling.SQLExceptionHandling(sqlException, "BL_UserMaster", "SaveUser", "SQL Error in BL_UserMaster");
                }
                catch (Exception exception)
                {
                    BL_ErrorHandling.GeneralExceptionHandling(exception, "BL_UserMaster", "SaveUser", "General Error in BL_UserMaster");
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                objConn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it breaks the code?"

Comment: after i make these changes the form on longer works i cannot save changes to or add new employees it doesn't seem to update the database

Comment: Are `InsertUserMaster` and `UpdateUserMaster` stored procedures in your database? If so, do they need to be modified to accommodate the new `UserPhone` field?

Comment: Thanks ConnersFan That is there is  stored procedures for these i need to update